# Adjust VS Predict on Stata

Tags: stata, prediction

I'm trying to obtain predicted values after a linear regression with Stata. However I don't find what the command Predict does with the covariates. I think that the command Adjust holds their values at their means for continuous variables and holds discrete variables at 1/number of categories for discrete covariates. But what does Predict do? Does it hold values at 0 for all covariates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict` uses own values of covariates for each observation.

`adjust` is an out-of-date command that has been superseded by `margins`. Margins can use own, means/modes/medians/percentiles with the `at()` option, or even a mixture of all these. By default, `margins` uses own values and then averages over the estimation sample.